# SWIFTUI:- Is there any way to turn off bouncing while scrolling the scrollview?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I created an application in SwiftUI and use vertical scrolling. I want to turn off bouncing while scrolling the scroll view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to turn off bounce for a SwiftUI list by turning off tableview bounce in the init().  I haven't tested it for scrollview but maybe you can do something similar?

```
init() {
    UITableView.appearance().bounces = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply restrict scrollView's bounce, but you can achieve this by UIScollView's property.

```
 UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
```

Add this in App-delegate or View's initialiser method. Hope This will help you.

Comment: appearance() doesn't have the "bounce" property anymore